# how do i create a sql which takes the last inserted record of each unique record?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table (inspect) which gets filled every time an inspector visits the station.

When an admin tries to view the inspect table, i would want to display all the records which satisfy these conditions:

1. Each record must hold unique station name
2. Displayed record must be the last updated record for that particular station

As of now, the sql I've used is

```
$sql = "select `StationID`,`DOI`,`due`,`StationName` from inspect group by `StationID`";
```

This displays perfectly, except it shows the first record of each unique station.

E.g. if the table has

```
StationID StationName      DOI         due
924         RMC      17-Mar-2014
924         RMC      20-Mar-2016    
926         IMD      23-Jan-2018                
926         IMD      18-Jan-2018                
926         IMD      18-Jan-2018                
926         IMD      18-Jan-2018     19-Jan-2019
```

my sql must display

```
924 RMC 20-Mar-2016
926 IMD 18-Jan-2018 19-Jan-2019
```

Comment: I don't have a primary key...

Comment: If StationID is auto increment column, then would this query not work? $sql = "select `StationID`,`DOI`,`due`,`StationName` from inspect  group by `StationName` ORDER BY `StationID` DESC";

Comment: I think there's a mistake somewhere in the question. If you group by StationID and it only returns those two records then you can't have all the unique values in your example table. What happens to 924 for example? StationID and StationName sound linked and you say there's no primary key so I suspect RMC should have an ID of 925 and IMD an ID of 929? It's not really possible to answer without clearing this up.

Comment: Are you intending to group by StationName or StationID? Is StationID really a unique value for each row? The order by wouldn't work as that only orders the final result (the two returned rows).

Comment: @BenThurley
yes, group by StationName, not by StationID, the data in StationID is wrong, technically, two rows of 924 and 4 rows of 926 should be the correct ID, I'll edit it up right away...
group by StationName is intended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some big if's to this answer since the question really needs clarifying. However, it is possible if we make the following assumptions.

- StationName is what you want to group by
- StationID is a unique incrementing ID (the primary key)

The following query would work.

```
select a.StationID, a.DOI, a.due, a.StationName from inspect a
where a.StationID = (
  select max(b.StationID) from inspect b  
  where b.StationName = a.StationName
)
group by a.StationName;
```

As evidenced in this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0935b/3)

Back to those assumptions... I think to achieve what you want, you must have a primary key. So if StationID isn't the primary key then you need to add one and use that column instead.

**Edit**
The question has now changed because as I suspected it had mistakes. You can group on StationID or StationName and get the same result so that bit doesn't matter. But I don't think you can get the results you want with that table structure.

First you need a way to get the "last updated record". You currently don't have a column that tells you this. The DOI column apparently gives you a clue but it is not unique and you have three rows there with the same date. The due column can't be relied upon because it is mostly null.

Second, once you have that column you have no way of using it to select only that record within the group by. You can only do this with a primary key. It's not a good table design if you don't have a means to refer to one row. It completely rules out any type of join.

Comment: StationID is not unique and not auto incrementing and not primary key, sorry for the confusions caused

Comment: i have added the primary key (srno), now how do i show what i wanted?

Comment: Thank you very much! this means a lot to me!

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "select * 
        from `inspect` 
        group by `StationID` 
        order by str_to_date(`DOI`, '%d-%b-%Y') desc";
```

You need to convert the `DOI` column to an actual date so that it can be ordered by the engine appropriately.